# Polars: How to reorder columns in a specific order?

Tags: python-polars

I cannot find how to reorder columns in a polars dataframe in the [polars DataFrame docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.html?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it is the same as `pandas`:

```
df = df[['PRODUCT', 'PROGRAM', 'MFG_AREA', 'VERSION', 'RELEASE_DATE', 'FLOW_SUMMARY', 'TESTSUITE', 'MODULE', 'BASECLASS', 'SUBCLASS', 'Empty', 'Color', 'BINNING', 'BYPASS', 'Status', 'Legend']]
```

Comment: As mentioned above, this method is disfavored as compared to using .select()

Answer (score 26):

Using the `select` method is the recommended way to sort columns in polars.

Example:

Input:

```
df
┌─────┬───────┬─────┐
│Col1 ┆ Col2  ┆Col3 │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ str   ┆ str │
╞═════╪═══════╪═════╡
│ a   ┆ x     ┆ p   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b   ┆ y     ┆ q   │
└─────┴───────┴─────┘
```

Output:

```
df.select(['Col3', 'Col2', 'Col1'])
or
df.select([pl.col('Col3'), pl.col('Col2'), pl.col('Col1)])

┌─────┬───────┬─────┐
│Col3 ┆ Col2  ┆Col1 │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ str   ┆ str │
╞═════╪═══════╪═════╡
│ p   ┆ x     ┆ a   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ q   ┆ y     ┆ b   │
└─────┴───────┴─────┘
```

Note:
While `df[['Col3', 'Col2', 'Col1']]` gives the same result (version 0.14), it is recommended ([link](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/selecting_data/selecting_data_intro.html)) that you use the select method instead.

> We strongly recommend selecting data with expressions for almost all
> use cases. Square bracket indexing is perhaps useful when doing
> exploratory data analysis in a terminal or notebook when you just want
> a quick look at a subset of data.
>
> For all other use cases we recommend using expressions because:
>
> 1. expressions can be parallelized
> 2. the expression approach can be used in lazy and eager mode while the indexing approach can only be used in eager mode
> 3. in lazy mode the query optimizer can optimize expressions

Answer (score 9):

That seems like a special case of projection to me.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "c": [1, 2],
    "a": ["a", "b"],
    "b": [True, False]
})

df.select(sorted(df.columns))
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬───────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b     ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ bool  ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═══════╪═════╡
│ a   ┆ true  ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b   ┆ false ┆ 2   │
└─────┴───────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without referencing the data frame explicitly? I.e. something that would work with method chaining?

Comment: You can use `pipe` for that.

Comment: What's the difference between `df.select(["a", "b"])`, `df.select(pl.col(["a", "b"]))`, and `df.select(pl.col("a"), pl.col("b"))`? Is there a preferred syntax?